# Model - View - Publisher as a design pattern?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, oop, node.js, comet

I thought I would ask about this here. Does anyone know of any work being done with regards to a 'MVP' design pattern involving push-based data transfer (not to be confused with Model-View-Presenter)?

I'd call it Model-View-Publisher, or perhaps Model-Subscriber-Publisher where a Subscriber is analogous to a View and a Publisher is analogous to a controller.

The idea is here is that instead of your typical controller that responds to client requests, you have a 'Publisher' which pushes data to client 'Subscribers' when some event occurs. The push would be via long polling / reverse ajax / comet or some other similar method.

Do any frameworks such as this exist, and if not, would it be a useful pattern? I'd be specifically interested in implementations in C# / Javascript on the client or maybe NodeJS on the back-end.

Alternatively, are there any MVC frameworks or implementations that provide controllers which push data to the client using technologies such as Comet?

Comment: I think Scala and Lift makes this quite easy, but I don't know enough to talk about it.

Comment: You may want to keep an eye on [flatiron](http://flatironjs.org/)

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but isnt this pattern just an 'Observer' Pattern? It is also known as the Publish/Subscriber pattern. http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx

Comment: @Aaron, it is certainly based on the observer pattern, but I wouldn't call it identical. If anything it would be a special case of the observer pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine support for web sockets will be coming soon. See [Websockets with ASP.NET MVC / MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890494/websockets-with-asp-net-mvc-mvvm) for current web socket support

Comment: I'd recommend socket.io for websockets instead.